# Netsuite Online HTML Form- Is there a way to map current customer fields to online form?

Tags: netsuite

I have created an online form to email to current customers so they can update their billing information.

The problem is when I try to include the current field values so the customer can update the fields based on whether or not the current values are correct, the form does not allow for two values for same field to exist on the form.

Is there a way to add the current field values and leave a blank text field on netsuite online forms?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the values from the customer as part of the query string but the standard form will render those as fixed, non-editable fields.

What I do is pass in the customer id, an expiration timestamp and a hash of the id, expiration and a secret key.

Then I use a custom template for the form. The template includes a script that passes the id, expiration and hash to a suitelet. The suitelet validates the hash and if the time is not past the expiration will return customer values as a JSON object. The form's script will then populate the customer fields with current values that the customer can then update.

Not fool proof but it does put security in the hands of the customer. To increase security you can make the expiration duration short and have your suitelet offer to send a new email link to the customer's registered email address.

What I actually try to do (depending on whether you are asking the customer to respond or whether the customer has reason to respond) is to route the customer to a category page that requires login. Then I just build my form from scratch and have the backing suitelet accept the form post as well. The form posts into an iFrame and the result uses postMessage to report status/completion etc. This is way more secure.